# How to manually change the ggplot2 legend to include vlines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've spent a bit of time on this from one rabbit hole to another. I would like to plot this data.

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(80,75,50,60,5,91,68,50,40,50),
                 event = c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e"), cell = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"))
```

This is as close as I have gotten to the plot I would like :

```
lines <- data.frame(intercepts = c("b","d"), names = c('treatment1','treatment2'))

ggplot(df, aes(x=event , y=value, group = cell, color =cell)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=cell), size =1) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=cell), size = 2) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        legend.key = element_rect(fill="white"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())+
  geom_vline(data = lines, aes(xintercept = intercepts, color = names, linetype = names)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "treatment1" = "green", "treatment2" = "purple")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("A" = "solid", "B" = "solid", "treatment1" = "dashed","treatment2"="dashed")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("A" = 18, "B" = 20, "treatment1" = 1, "treatment2"= 1))
```

[image: Ggplot]

The only issue is the legend does not look like the plot lines. A and B should look like this [image] in the legend, while treatment 1 and treatment 2 should be vertical, dashed, and of their respective colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but please check it out. Please let me know if linetype for `B` needed to be solid or etc.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=event , y=value, group = cell, color =cell)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=cell), size =1) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=cell), size = 2) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        legend.key = element_rect(fill="white"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())+
  geom_vline(data = lines, aes(xintercept = intercepts, color = names, linetype = names), show.legend = F) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "blue", "treatment1" = "green", "treatment2" = "purple"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                       linetype = c(1,3,3,3), #HERE
                       shape = c(19, 17, NA, NA)
                     ))) +
  guides(shape = "none", linetype = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: The problem still is that the legend doesn't really match the lines. The A B should have the solid and dashed lines as part of their legends respectively. Treatment 1 and treatment 2 shouldn't have the horizontal lines as part of their legends either. I'm wondering if one of the other geoms is adding those issues to the legend. I'm looking now for an aesthetic that turns off geoms from showing in the legend.

Comment: @pabstack Ah both `treatment1` and `treatment2` should not have dashed line. It can be solved. Please wait.

Comment: @pabstack I edit my code. In code above, you may find linetype for `treatment` in `#HERE` line of `scale_color_manual` part.

Comment: Hey that got it! Thanks! I was really at the end of my rope the other night with that. I appreciate the help.